# How to manage multiple domains resources for the same person?

Tags: cross-domain, cas

I'm pretty new to the world of CAS, my company decided to take a shot at it.
So this is the scenario: let's say we have 3 or more domains where an user, let's say john smith, exist in each domain.
In domain A is john.smit@domainA and is enabled to appA,appB and so on
In domain B is j.smith@domainB is enabled to appC and appD
I've been asked to integrate a CAS solution, with SAML, in which the user can authenticate and still get access to all the applications he/she is enabled across all the domains were he/she exists.
I discovered that you can configure multiple ldap in the CAS server,I wonder, if is possible to retrieve all the applications or resources he/she is enabled in other domains, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CAS!

What you need to do is,

1. Register applications A and B and C with the CAS server.
2. For each application, define an access strategy that only permits access to the application if the principal/user has special attributes (matching that domain) or if the user-id matches a pattern. For instance, the access strategy for application A might say: "Only permit user access if the user-id matches `@domainA`"
3. When each user logs in and attempts to access an application, the strategy is activated and consulted as part of the application policy to determine entry rules.

All changes take place inside the CAS Server; no modifications to the applications are expected. You can run attribute queries across all data sources (LDAP, AD, etc) to collect info about the user. The software will combine and merge results as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Let's say... what can i do if i can not edit the applications cause they are made from other companies ?
I'd like to give ( if possible) the user who access, all the resources/attributes it has across all the domains he/she is enabled despite having different username.
i'm sure i need something to identify him which must be unique, like birth date, across all the domains

Comment: The solution above does not require that you edit the application or make any modifications to it. All changes are done on the CAS server side, which you surely control. You can run attribute queries across all data sources (LDAP, AD, etc) to collect info about the user. The software will combine and merge results as appropriate.

Comment: All right, wonderful! Thanks for the answer again!
I'll mark that as an answer, i'll try to do what i can, if you know, there are some guides or tutorials, i'd very appreciate that!

Comment: Check out https://fawnoos.com/blog (Disclaimer: I am the primary author). Also checkout https://apereo.github.io/ (which hosts the same blog posts before I moved over to fawnoos.com)